# Are These Sentences Equivalent or is One More Appropriate than the Others? (Present Progressive Tense)

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense, present-progressive

These all seem equally "valid" to me:

```
"I have recently been reading some research papers about..."
"I recently have been reading some research papers about..."
"I have been recently reading some research papers about..."
"Recently, I have been reading some research papers about..."
```

Are these all equivalent or is one more "appropriate" than the other, and why?
Thanks!

Comment: They're all okay. I'd avoid *recently reading* for the Rs. Little touches like that help the reader who's vocalizing (reading to themselves).

Comment: (1) and (4) sound more natural. 'Recently' may also be placed at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adverbs + Present Perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151202/adverbs-present-perfect)